# Renaming Settings.bundle and not Bundle Display Name?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, settings.bundle

Is there a way to change the title of the Settings.bundle for your iOS app besides changing the name of the apps `Bundle Display Name`?

```
Settings.bunlde Display: Something Long
Springboard icon name  : Something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to display "Something Long" as the title of your app's root settings screen, instead of the app's bundle display name "Something", right?

Unfortunately you cannot do this for the app's root settings screen, even if your Settings.bundle/Root.plist file defines a "Settings Page Title", it will ignore it and show the app's bundle display name.